# TypeError: no implicit conversion of Array into String

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms

I am receiving a error on the line `= select_tag :ethnicity, ['Asian', 'Black', 'Biracial', 'Indian', 'Hispanic/Latin', 'Middle Eastern', 'Native American', 'Pacific Islander', 'White', 'Other'], prompt: 'ethnicity/race'` that reads `no implicit conversion of Array into String`

Can someone assist?

index.html.slim:

```
  = form_tag searches_path, method: :get do
          .select4
            .col.col7 style='margin-left: 10px;width:233px;'
              = select_tag :ethnicity, ['Asian', 'Black', 'Biracial', 'Indian', 'Hispanic/Latin', 'Middle Eastern', 'Native American', 'Pacific Islander', 'White', 'Other'], prompt: 'ethnicity/race'
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this

```
= select_tag :ethnicity, options_for_select(['Asian', 'Black', 'Biracial', 'Indian', 'Hispanic/Latin', 'Middle Eastern', 'Native American', 'Pacific Islander', 'White', 'Other'])
```

Note the `options_for_select` method

[Source](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormTagHelper.html#method-i-select_tag)

Answer (score 2):

> `select_tag(name, option_tags = nil, options = {}) public`
>
> Helpers::FormOptions can be used to create common select boxes such as countries, time zones, > or associated records. *option_tags* is a string containing the option tags for the select box.
>
> http://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/FormTagHelper/select_tag

The second parameter should be a HTML string - not an array. You can use [`options_for_select`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormOptionsHelper.html) to generate option tags from an array.